# Preventing caching of javascripts and css while developing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am currently developing and running my site from Visual Studio 2010. The site is launched in Google Chrome upon compiling.

Somewhere along the way, things are being cached.  I can make a change to a javascript function, but unless i clear the cache in chrome, the old version of the script is being run.

I am running Visual Studio 2010 with .net 3.5 and the latest version of Google Chrome.

Is it possible to automatically load the latest script every time?  I really don't want to add a ?parameter onto my script tag each time I save and compile.  It's getting old having to clear the cache each time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple method that I use is to either <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> each time chrome is opened, OR, you can kill the local web server prior to running the app:

[image]

See list of chrome shortcuts for additional reading: [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179).  Observe that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> as well as <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> will reload the current page while ignoring the cached content.

I typically use the above method instead of disabling cache alltogether (from chrome settings) because this is a localized case where I WANT to do away with the cache.  All other situations (like normal browsing) I would prefer to keep the cache.

Answer (score 8):

Open Chrome Dev Tools. In the bottom right corner there's a gear icon. Click it and click "Disable cache."

Also there's an option "Dock to right". Try it out, perhaps, you'll Like it!

Answer (score 4):

You could also get the server to add the following header to requests outgoing from the server:

```
cache-control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
```

Also, you can start chrome with a command line flag that disables caching. To do this, create a new shortcut and type in the target box the following, replacing  with your own username for your computer:

```
C:\Users\<username here>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disk-cache-size=1 -media-cache-size=1
```

The flags have to be set to one, because 0 is unlimited. The numbers are in bytes.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** To reload the page just once without the cache, press `CTRL+SHIFT+R`. This *should* work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can always import the javascript source with some parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/scriptFile.js?28361823"></script>
```

Most people use a getTimeInMillis()  function to populate the request. This will bypass the cache (usually) and you'll get the newest data.

This will also force your users to get the javascript again, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent caching css or javascript files in browsers use random version id in your link. for example use this:

```
<link   href=<%="'mystyle.css?version="+ DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") +"'"%>   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

where myStyle.css is stylesheet file and DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") function used for generate random different version id.

Answer (score 0):

**Js and css version changes vary for many applications.
You can check here for detailed information.**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

1. You need to define a meta tag in Index.html, you can do this as follows.
   Using HTML:
2. You can add Header to each Ajax request.

   ```
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); //Proxies.
   ```
3. Using ASP.NET-MVC, you can add version to _Layout.cshtml as follows.

   ```
   @{
             string versionId = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
     }
     <link href="~/assets/libs/toastr/nuget/content/content/toastr.min.css?version={@versionId}" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="~/assets/css/bootstrap.css?version={@versionId}" rel="stylesheet" />
   ```